# Percona Toolkit Vs. Openark Kit. Schema change

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, percona

I tried to add unique index to 2 columns of an RDS DB table with **pt-online-schema-change** and it failed with the error like:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation [for Statement "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0"] at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 4663.
```

But using **oak-online-alter-table**, my table is altering. The procedure is not completed, but I see no errors and the output is like:

```
...
-- Copying range (1230004), (1231683), progress: 24%
```

Do these tools implement different approaches to alter tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to really worry about in this instance.

According to the [MySQL Documentation on the SUPER privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super)

> The SUPER privilege enables an account to use CHANGE MASTER TO, KILL
>   or mysqladmin kill to kill threads belonging to other accounts (you
>   can always kill your own threads), PURGE BINARY LOGS, configuration
>   changes using SET GLOBAL to modify global system variables, the
>   mysqladmin debug command, enabling or disabling logging, performing
>   updates even if the read_only system variable is enabled, starting and
>   stopping replication on slave servers, specification of any account in
>   the DEFINER attribute of stored programs and views, and enables you to
>   connect (once) even if the connection limit controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable is reached.
>
> To create or alter stored functions if binary logging is enabled, you
>   may also need the SUPER privilege, as described in Section 18.7,
>   “Binary Logging of Stored Programs”.

Disabling the binary logging of statements in a DB Session requires the SUPER privilege.

In fact, according to the documentation on [`pt-online-schema-change`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-online-schema-change.html)

> --bin-log
>
> Allow binary logging (SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1). By default binary logging is
>   turned off because in most cases the --tmp-table does not need to be
>   replicated. Also, performing an online schema change in a replication
>   environment requires careful planning else replication may be broken;
>   see “REPLICATION”.

From this, you can conclude that this is indeed normal behavior for pt-online-schema-change. It attempted to disable binary logging in its session by default.

## **Recommendation**

Try running `pt-online-schema-change` as root@localhost. That user should all privs active.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer! 

According your recommendation, unfortunately, it's not possible on RDS.

Comment: It is not possible on AWS RDS.